# gridview export not export data

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

here is my ASPX Code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" EnableEventValidation="false" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default4.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default4" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Export GridView1" 
        onclick="Button3_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Export GridView1" 
        onclick="Button4_Click" />
        <br /><br />
    <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server">
        <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Export GridView1" 
        onclick="Button1_Click" />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="f_casenum" HeaderText="Case Number" 
                SortExpression="f_casenum" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="f_invoice" HeaderText="Invoice Number" 
                SortExpression="f_invoice" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Export GridView2" 
        onclick="Button2_Click" />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="f_casenum" HeaderText="Case Number" 
                SortExpression="f_casenum" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="f_invoice" HeaderText="Invoice Number" 
                SortExpression="f_invoice" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>
        </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:paconn %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [c_emi]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

and my c# code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

public partial class Default4 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ExportFile.xls");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            using (StringWriter sw1 = new StringWriter())
            {
                HtmlTextWriter hw1 = new HtmlTextWriter(sw1);

                GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
                this.GridView1.DataBind();

                GridView1.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
                foreach (TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
                {
                    cell.BackColor = GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
                }
                foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                {
                    row.BackColor = Color.White;
                    foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                    {
                        if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            cell.BackColor = GridView1.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cell.BackColor = GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor;
                        }
                        cell.CssClass = "textmode";
                    }
                }

                GridView1.RenderControl(hw1);
                string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
                Response.Write(style);
                Response.Output.Write(sw1.ToString());
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GridView2.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ExportFile.xls");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            using (StringWriter sw1 = new StringWriter())
            {
                HtmlTextWriter hw1 = new HtmlTextWriter(sw1);

                GridView2.AllowPaging = false;
                this.GridView2.DataBind();

                GridView2.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
                foreach (TableCell cell in GridView2.HeaderRow.Cells)
                {
                    cell.BackColor = GridView2.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
                }
                foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
                {
                    row.BackColor = Color.White;
                    foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                    {
                        if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            cell.BackColor = GridView2.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cell.BackColor = GridView2.RowStyle.BackColor;
                        }
                        cell.CssClass = "textmode";
                    }
                }

                GridView2.RenderControl(hw1);
                string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
                Response.Write(style);
                Response.Output.Write(sw1.ToString());
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        //Verifies that the control is rendered
    }
    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
    }
    protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["paconn"].ToString());
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM c_emi", con);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(com);

        sqlDa.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView2.DataSource = dt;
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

the problem is that when i click on Export GridView1 button it export all data of GridView1 perfectly but when i click on Export GridView2 button it export data to excel and my excel file contain only this " .textmode { } ".
i think that error occur when i bind gridview2 using c#.

i am using asp.net c# visual studio 2010.

Comment: Why do you bind if no rows?

Comment: i he wont bind the grid view then existing Rows will be displayed to grid!

Comment: that was only an example.

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE you ar right Sir...thanx for helping me.

Comment: hi @user3730685! does this solve your problem?

Comment: please mark as answer if it helped u!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have not bind your `GridView2` with any `DataSource` by Default which you do for `GridView1`. Your markup of `GridView2` must have some `DataSource` and must `Bind` to `GridView2`

Hope this helps you!